# how to get google URL results list, using the custom search javascript reference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, google-custom-search

I'm using the the javascript api to render search results on my page, however i'm parsing the google results in a "dirty" format, by using jquery to read the contents of various dom tags.

Is there a method in the javascript API, to return the URL list? or should i manually have to parse the google results?

Comment: Check out purl.js https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl